# tooltip the data-placement="right" is not working [edit]

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip

First of all, the tooltip is working for all the direction, top, bottom and left. But for the right is not working.

So I think that maybe is a problem with the CSS or HTML structure. (But the tooltip is in a position absolute, so I don't know why is this happening. )

**HTML**

```html
<li class="">
    <div class="hover-highlight ml-2">
        <a class="" href="#">
            <i data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Dashboard" class="icon-meter"></i>
            <span>Dasboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the **javascript** I am doing this:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement: 'right'
    });
});
```

Like I said, for any other placement it is working fine. But for the right it broke!

In fact, I don't know why, but it is rendering with the left properties:

```
<div class="tooltip fade show bs-tooltip-left" role="tooltip" id="tooltip558151" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(125px, 207px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;" x-placement="left">
    <div class="arrow" style="top: 8px;" />
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Dashboard</div>
</div>
```

**The problem**

Okay, I found the problem. looks like automatically bootstrap push your text according to the parent div. For example, if your tooltip is at the right of the window, you can't force it to be placed into the right.

I don't know how to fix this behaviour.

**CODE**

Please, check the code [here:](http://jsfiddle.net/valrob/q7gasyh1/1/)

Comment: can you create fiddle or stack snippet?

Comment: I will try, give me time.

Comment: @20yco done: https://www.bootply.com/2zE4Zb3cva

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is the margins of div, take a look:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]',placement: 'top' });
});
```

```css
.theproblem {
  margin-left:140px;
  margin-top:140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" title="Gestión de Usuarios" class="theproblem">
    Hola mundo
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

also [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/j7Lxhgnv/12/)

Comment: But in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/j7Lxhgnv/)  you are pushing it to the left and is going to the right. .

Comment: sorry, changed direction

Comment: In your example, I can push it to the bottom or the right. But to the left or top is impossible

Comment: @ValRob don't forget to click 'run' at the top of fiddle after change code

Comment: Yeah, but, **it can not go to the top or the left**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186366/discussion-between-valrob-and-20yco).

Comment: yeah, thanks. It looks like it needs a minimun space to show the tooltip. So the solution is give a bigger size to the parent element.

Comment: @ValRob yep, please don't forget upvote, not only check as answer )

Comment: problem is that would drastically alter the look, how do you do this with out changing the look

Comment: having a place is the key, tooltip needs a place to be displayed. for exampe if you have element on top of screen and if you try to tooltip with placement "top", it will display right or something, but if you give a margin-top: 50 (which creates space for top tooltip), it will display at top

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with the differences between bootstrap4 using "**data-toggle**" and "**data-placement**" and bootstrap5 using "**data-bs-toggle**" and "**data-bs-placement**".

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/
  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 6):

In the event this helps anyone arriving here in future, the fix for a similar issue I encountered was setting the boundary to "window" which prevents the tooltip from being constrained to within it's parent. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options for additional options.

```
<button title="tooltip text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-boundary="window">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  Using: data-boundary="window"  saved my day!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function() {

  $(this).data('bs.tooltip').config.placement = 'right';// For dynamic position
  $(this).data('bs.tooltip').config.boundary= 'right'; // Used for tooltip boundary range
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the **text** in a data property of the element

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement: 'right'
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<li class="">
  <div class="hover-highlight ml-2">
    <a class="" href="#">
        <i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Dashboard" class="icon-meter">
          <span>Dasboard</span>
        </i>
      </a>
  </div>
</li>               
                
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because the parent div's overflow was set to auto.
So I changed it from `overflow: auto` to: `overflow: visible` and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should put the placement in a data property of the element:

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"> tooltip </button>
```